# Regex negated capture group returns answer

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

In python, how can I prevent this from returning a list of empty strings?

```
>>> re.findall(re.compile("(?!lala)"),"lala")
['', '', '', '']
```

Comment: What were you trying to achieve? Your regular expression doesn't make sense. Could you expand on your question and show us some examples where you'd expect a match that isn't empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for an empty string that is not followed by the text `lala`, a negative lookahead assertion.

Since there are 4 such positions with an empty string (in-between the letters and at the end), there are 4 empty matches.

It is returning exactly what your are looking for, perhaps you were looking for something else instead?

Answer (score -1):

first of all: `(?!lala)` is not a very good regular expression. (as you have found out yourself)
secondly, findall will look for pretty much anything it can find, and since you arent really looking for anything, and you are looking for it in 4 characters, you get 4 empty strings.

to fix this, you should help your regular expressions a bit

try this link http://regexr.com?32dcm

which i have copied your regex and some random lines to show you an example. also below:

`^(?!lala).*$`

will match any line which does not start with lala. 
since you didnt make your exact desired clear, this is what i think you are trying to do.

Comment: `(?!lala)` is obviously a legal regular expression. The re module compiled it, it returns results. It means: match what precedes against anything that is not followed by `lala`, where  *what precedes* is an empty string. Note that there are *4* results, not 5, as the empty string at the start of the input *is* followed by `lala`, and thus doesn't satisfy the limitation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters as usual martijn, you are correct. thanks for correcting me.